# iPhone swift app development using WKWebview - How to trigger a local notification immediately when a javascript event happens

Tags: javascript, iphone, swift, wkwebview

I am writing an iPhone app in swift using WKWebView that loads a web page, and I need to trigger a local notification once a particular javascript even happens (once I see this "danger-badge" image on the page, which pops up via javascript). Currently I am able to "schedule" a local notification once I see this javascript event (see code below), but I need to trigger the local notification immediately after the javascript event, whenever it happens. Currently I am only able to schedule a reoccurring local notification.

I am not doing push notifications because the app is just a basic browser that points to a website that has javascript events on it, so basically I want the app to mirror the notification that happens on the web page that's loaded.

Here is my swift code using the WKWebView (pardon the comments. I've been playing with this for a while):

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    var webView: WKWebView!

```
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()




    let js: String = " var parentNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('badge badge-danger'); var text; text = 'Nodename: ' + parentNodes[0].nodeName + ' Classname: ' +  parentNodes[0].className + ' ' + parentNodes[0].textContent + ' \\n';  window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(text); "



    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    contentController.removeAllUserScripts()
    contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
    // Add ScriptMessageHandler
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "callbackHandler"
    )

    webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true



    view = webView

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://websiteurl.com/dev")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)




}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   //... 


}

// Implement `WKScriptMessageHandler`，handle message which been sent by JavaScript
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    //if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
    let messageBody = "\(message.body)"


    if #available(iOS 10, *)
    {

        //UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        //let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        //center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
        //center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() // To remove all pending notifications which are not delivered yet but scheduled.*/

        if messageBody.contains("badge badge-danger")
        {

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { (didAllow, error) in})

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

            content.title = "You have a new notification!"
            //content.badge = 1
            content.body = "new notification..."



            let date = Date()

            var triggerNow = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from:date)

            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

            print(trigger.nextTriggerDate())

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: content.title, content: content, trigger: trigger)



            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in
                print(error)
            })

            print("JavaScript message: TEST \(message.body)")
        }

    }





}

}
```